# How to save time zone for each record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have one model with name `Job` I have a column name with `due_date` for that column I want to save time_zone

This is my code:

```
def create
   @job = Job.new(params[:job])

#saving time_zone
   if params[:job][:assigned_to] != "NULL"
      @assigned_to = params[:job][:assigned_to]
      @user = User.find_by_name(@assigned_to)
      Time.zone = @user.time_zone
      @job.due_date = Time.use_zone(@user.time_zone) {Time.zone.parse("#{params[:job][:due_date]}").in_time_zone(@user.time_zone)}
   end

   if @job.save
end
```

please help me how to save time_zone for each record.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has posted an answer to this yet, here is my trivial answer.  Generate a regex for each time-zone and apply it to `due_date`

Something like this:

```
re = Regexp.new('ADT|AKDT|AKST|AST|CDT|CST|EDT|EGST|EGT|EST|HADT|HAST|MDT|MST|NDT|NST|PDT|PMDT|PMST|PST|WGST|WGT')
ans = @job.due_date.to_s re
```

Should parse out the timezone for you to save.